# Generic hierarchical DataView class with dynamic levels of sort keys

Tags: c#, dataview, sortedlist

When we create a DataView with sort on multiple columns, we are forced to specify values of all the columns when using FindRows.

Example, if I have:

```
dv1 = new DataView(tbl1, null, "Col1, Col2, Col3", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
```

I am forced to specify values for all 3 columns when using FindRows.

It is not possible to retrieve all rows for a particular value of Col1 and "any" value for Col2 and Col3.

This is possible in a SortedList where I can have nested SortedList. So, the top level SortedList will have key as Col1, and value as another SortedList. The 2nd level SortedList will have key as Col2, and value as another SortedList. Finally, the 3rd level SortedList will have key as Col3, and the references to the DataRows.

Using such a SortedList, it is possible to write methods, like:

```
public DataRowView[] FindAny(object[] keys)
```

where if the keys array contains only 1 key, the code can find the 2nd level SortedList from the 1st level SortedList for the key, and then loop through the 2nd and 3rd level SortedList and return all rows, as they belong to 1st key.

My question is whether anyone has already written such a SortedList class which can take dynamic number of keys, and work with any DataTable / DataRow.

Note: 
1. This question has nothing to do with presentation layer. I am looking for a helper class for data processing, say for analysing huge volume of data in multiple excel sheets.
2. I am not looking for a LINQ based solution currently. I will migrate to LINQ in future.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are keen then `System.Linq.Dynamic` (Nuget library) can solve the issue at hand now

Comment: can you pls post the Linq code for my future reference. Let me see how easy it is to migrate

Comment: Check out the solution underneath which use the `RowFilter` property of DataView to do the filtering

Answer (score 0):

I managed to write my own generic class, which implements a hierarchial view of the data. Improvements in this are welcome.

```
    public class HDataView
{
    private SortedList mapDataRows;
    int numMapLevels;

    public HDataView(DataTable tbl, string[] colNames)
    {
        object colVal = null;
        string colName = "";
        SortedList currLvlMap = null, nextLvlMap = null;
        DataRow dr1 = null;
        ArrayList arlLastLvlData;

        mapDataRows = new SortedList();
        numMapLevels = colNames.Length;

        for (int i = 0; i < tbl.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dr1 = tbl.Rows[i];
            currLvlMap = mapDataRows;
            for (int j = 0; j < colNames.Length; j++)
            {
                colName = colNames[j];
                colVal = dr1[colName];

                if (j == colNames.Length - 1)
                {
                    arlLastLvlData = (ArrayList)currLvlMap[colVal];
                    if (arlLastLvlData == null)
                    {
                        arlLastLvlData = new ArrayList();
                        currLvlMap[colVal] = arlLastLvlData;
                    }
                    arlLastLvlData.Add(dr1);
                }
                else
                {
                    nextLvlMap = (SortedList)currLvlMap[colVal];
                    if (nextLvlMap == null)
                    {
                        nextLvlMap = new SortedList();
                        currLvlMap[colVal] = nextLvlMap;
                    }

                    //For the next column, the current nextLvlMap will become the prevLvlMap
                    currLvlMap = nextLvlMap;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public ArrayList FindAnyRows(object[] keys)
    {
        object keyVal = "";
        ArrayList arlDataRows = null, arlCurrRows = null;
        SortedList startLvlMap = null, currLvlMap = null, nextLvlMap = null;
        int mapLevel = 1, startLevel = 0;

        currLvlMap = mapDataRows;
        mapLevel = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
        {
            keyVal = keys[i];

            if (currLvlMap == null)
            {
                break;
            }

            if (i == numMapLevels - 1)
            {
                arlDataRows = (ArrayList)currLvlMap[keyVal];
            }
            else
            {
                nextLvlMap = (SortedList)currLvlMap[keyVal];
                currLvlMap = nextLvlMap;
                mapLevel++;
            }
        }

        if (arlDataRows == null)
        {
            arlDataRows = new ArrayList();
        }

        if (keys.Length > 0 && keys.Length < numMapLevels)
        {
            if (currLvlMap != null)
            {
                startLvlMap = currLvlMap;
                startLevel = mapLevel;

                if (mapLevel == numMapLevels)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < startLvlMap.Count; j++)
                    {
                        arlCurrRows = (ArrayList)startLvlMap.GetByIndex(j);
                        if (arlCurrRows != null)
                        {
                            arlDataRows.AddRange(arlCurrRows);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < startLvlMap.Count; i++)
                    {
                        mapLevel = startLevel;
                        currLvlMap = startLvlMap;

                        //travel full depth of this map, for each element of this map
                        for (; mapLevel <= numMapLevels; mapLevel++)
                        {
                            if (mapLevel == numMapLevels)
                            {
                                for (int j = 0; j < currLvlMap.Count; j++)
                                {
                                    arlCurrRows = (ArrayList)currLvlMap.GetByIndex(j);
                                    if (arlCurrRows != null)
                                    {
                                        arlDataRows.AddRange(arlCurrRows);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //Next level of current element of the starting map
                                nextLvlMap = (SortedList)currLvlMap.GetByIndex(i);
                                currLvlMap = nextLvlMap;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return arlDataRows;
    }
}
```